# Git: Removing or replacing master branch with head

Tags: git, bitbucket

I got to a certain point in my project, and something messed up so I checked out an older version. I thought that I made my current checked out version the master version and discarded the version that was messed up. It looks like that didn't happen because after running:

```
git push -u origin master
```

I received these errors:

```
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://username@bitbucket.org/username/project.git'
hint: Updates were rejected because the tip of your current branch is behind
hint: its remote counterpart. Integrate the remote changes (e.g.
hint: 'git pull ...') before pushing again.
hint: See the 'Note about fast-forwards' in 'git push --help' for details
```

I have a rudimentary understanding of git and don't want to revert to or integrate the demon master branch. I'm pretty sure that 'git pull' is exactly what I don't want. What command am I looking for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The published history (on the bitbucket "origin" side) is:

```
--o--o--o--o--O (origin/master)
```

On your side:

```
--o--o--o--o (master)
```

If you want to replace `origin/master` by `master`, you will have to `push --force -u origin master`.
Be cautious though, and check if others are already using `origin/master` *before* changing its history.